# Passing a XML custom attributes from a custom UI component to a custom UI sub-components

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-xml, android-custom-attributes

I have a custom made UI component which have inside another custom made UI component (which is separated  for convenience purposes).

I want to be able to pass my own attributes to the father component, and read them inside the sub-component. In that way, the only thing the developer has to see is the father component, w/o needing to know there's another component inside.

For instance, this is the application's main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:udinic="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.udinic"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.udinic.FatherComponent android:id="@+id/fatherComp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    udinic:itemNum="9"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the father component's xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:udinic="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.udinic"
android:id="@+id/fatherLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.udinic.SubComponent android:id="@+id/subComp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    udinic:itemNum=<<Get the itemNum passed to me>>
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I didn't find any way to do this using the **XMLs only**. Does anyone knows anything that can help solving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the constructor of your father class to pass the value into the sub class.

```
public FatherClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs, LAYOUT);
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomLayout);
    //for string attribute
    textView.setText(getStringAttribute(typedArray, R.styleable.CustomLayout_labelText));
    //for resources
    int textAppearance = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomLayout_textAppearance, -1);
    textView.setTextAppearance(context, textAppearance);
    //for integers
    int inputType = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CustomLayout_inputType, -1);
    editText.setInputType(inputType);
}
```